# Off the shelf JavaScript based CSP alternative - is it safe?

Tags: content-security-policy

Are off the shelf CSP alternatives like Ensighten used by BritishAirways any good/safe? As and example, the way the bootstrap script seems to work is to bind its own proxy methods to `XMLHttpRequest` `Open`/`Send` which then check the requested domain against the list of allowed domains. Anything attempting to talk to unapproved domains get a fake response. Is this approach as safe as CSP? Is it possible for any scripts to remove Ensighten's bindings and set it back to native code?

Comment: As an example check `window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` on britishairways site and its no longer native code but is bound to a proxy method

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not as safe as a CSP. All you would need to do is create an empty `iframe` and you can get a full set of unmodified globals from that `iframe`'s window object.

Without a CSP, it would also be relatively easy to send data out to another domain using GET parameters in the `src` of an `img` tag for example. You could also use a `form` to send POST data via JavaScript (using an `iframe` you can even avoid a redirect).

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest was just an example. All resources are checked for approved domains and the rest of the URL for any restricted data being sent irrespective of the HttpRequest method.

Comment: @Displayname Globals patching cannot prevent you from creating an `img` tag with an arbitrary `src` to my knowledge.

Comment: As far as I know they override the creation of new elements on the page too. Thereby messing around with the src URL.

Comment: @Displayname It does not appear to, and I'm not sure it would even be possible (`innerHTML` can be used to parse HTML, bypassing any hijacking new element creation). I was successfully able to create an image tag that made an external request on the britishairways website using the following. `var img=document.createElement('img');img.src='https://example.com/';document.body.appendChild(img);`